# Bind an image and a paragraph together

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, block, binding

I have multiple blocks of text and each block is associated with an image. I am trying to wrap each image with its associated paragraph individually and so on. I want the next block of text and image to start after previous and not to overlap with each other.
Following is the sample code i've been using. and the respective result.

```
%Image for First text block
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{demo}
\end{wrapfigure}
%First Text
\entry{Abbreviated}{uh-bree-vee-ey-tid}{Adjective}{Constituting a shorter or smaller version of}
\\
%Image for Second text block
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{demo}
\end{wrapfigure}
%Second Text
\entry{Aberration}{ab-uh-rey-shuh n}{Noun}{The act of deviating from the ordinary, usual, or normal type.}
```

The output i'm getting is,

[image]

Whereas i want the second block of text and image to start when first block has ended.

[image]

How can i bind the image and text together?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please create a full, compilable minimal example including the documentclass and the used packages (e.g., `\entry` in your current code looks like it comes from a package). For the question itself: maybe a `tabular` (instead of `wrapfigure`) could help?

Comment: You can use a couple of minipages.  You can try \parbox, but \parbox does not change \textwidth.